# How to make a "for" loop on the condition of a number interval Xcode Swift2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hey I'm trying to figure out how to tally up soccer goals on the condition that the goal was scored in under 45 minutes, but the func has some slight errors with swift 2. Any help? Thanks!
[image]
Code:

```
 var barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals : [String : Int] = ["barcelonaGoal1":21,"RealMadridGoal2":23,"barcelonaGoal3":24,"RealMadridGoal4":27]


   func Run() {
    var goalCount=0
    for (goal,numbers) in barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals{
        for(var number in numbers) {
            if(number < 45)
            goalCount++

        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the errors, specificically?

Comment: Why you are using such  complex approach? You are causing syntax errors

Comment: oh ok thanks for the heads up

Comment: Did you want to sum up each `Int` that's less than 45 in your `[String, Int]` or did you just want to count which ones are less than 45? I based my answer on the latter since it looked like that's what you were going for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra `for..in` loop in there that's not needed:

```
for(var number in numbers) {
```

It also has an extraneous `(` and `)` around it

```
for var number in numbers {
```

Here is a working version of your code:

```
var barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals = ["barcelonaGoal1":21,"RealMadridGoal2":23,"barcelonaGoal3":24,"RealMadridGoal4":27]

func run() -> Int { // functions should start with lower case
  var goalCount=0
  for (_,numbers) in barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals where numbers < 45 {
    goalCount++
  }
  return goalCount
}

let goalCount = run()
```

And the functional way would be something like:

```
let goalCount = goals.reduce(0) {
  if $0.1.1 < 45 {
    return $0.0 + 1
  }
  return $0.0
}
```

With explanation:

```
var goals = [
  "barcelonaGoal1" :21,
  "RealMadridGoal2":23,
  "barcelonaGoal3" :24,
  "RealMadridGoal4":27,
  "RealMadridGoal5":45]

// For our use reduce takes an initial value of Int
// and a combine function of type
// (Int, (String, Int)) -> Int
//
// Reduce will call the closure once with
// each value in the map and the previous return value
let goalCount = goals.reduce(0, combine: {
  (initial:Int, current:(key:String, value:Int)) -> Int in
  var currentCount = initial

  // print to show input and output of closure
  print( "parameters:(\(initial), (\"\(current.key)\", \(current.value)))", terminator:", ")
  defer {
    print("return:\(currentCount)")
  }
  // end printing

  if current.value < 45 {
    ++currentCount // add 1 to the running total
    return currentCount
  }
  return currentCount
})

// console output:
//   parameters:(0, ("barcelonaGoal1", 21)), return:1
//   parameters:(1, ("RealMadridGoal4", 27)), return:2
//   parameters:(2, ("RealMadridGoal5", 45)), return:2
//   parameters:(2, ("RealMadridGoal2", 23)), return:3
//   parameters:(3, ("barcelonaGoal3", 24)), return:4
```

Comment: Glad to help! The functional way is great if you learn it, it can really simplify your code. The functions `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` are very powerful.

Comment: @Hunter I added more detail on the closure so you can study it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

For solving of you're problem try to use functional programing that is introduced in swift :

```
var barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals : [String : Int] = ["barcelonaGoal1":95,"RealMadridGoal2":23,"barcelonaGoal3":24,"RealMadridGoal4":27]

var filtered = barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals.filter { (team:String, minute:Int) -> Bool in

    var state = false
    if (minute > 45)
    {
        return true
    }
    return state
}


let totalCount = filtered.count
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
func Run() {
    var goalCount=0
    for (_, score) in barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals {
            if(score < 45) {
                goalCount++
            }
        }
    print(goalCount)
}
```